# middleman blog articles not rendered on github pages

Tags: github-pages, middleman

I've deployed my blog to github pages. Index page works fine, but when I click on post page, it forces browser to download file instead of rendering post.

I want to use pretty urls so I've followed middleman docs.
I get this error 'Failed to load resource: frame loading interrupted'

In my config file I have:

```
activate :directory_indexes
set :relative_links, true

activate :blog do |blog|
  blog.prefix = "blog"
  blog.permalink = ":year/:month/:title"
end
```

It works fine locally though. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so the issue was that files generated after build process were missing extension (html).

Since `directory_indexes` option is on, you should end up with `directory/index.html`, where directory's name is actually your blog post name.

To fix it, make sure you add the extension to permalink settings, just like that.

```
blog.permalink = "{year}/{month}/{title}.html"
```